# How to tell the version of a MySQL dump?

Tags: mysql, version

I have an old dump from a MySQL database.  I think it was somewhere around version 5.7.  My question is, how do I see the version of MySQL the dump was running on at the time of the dump?

Answer (score 3):

So, the dump file is just a text file.  In the beginning of the file it shows the "Server version:".

````
# head nextcloud-db.sql 
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.30, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: nextcloud
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.30-log```
````